# wpf: override label content when currently bound item is null

Tags: wpf

I want to set a `Label` (or `TextBox`) default string as long as the binding value is null. This works fine for any other property than `Content`, for example:

```
        <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource}, Path=/Label}">
            <Label.ContentStringFormat>Details for pump curve: {0}</Label.ContentStringFormat>

            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource header}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource}, Path=/}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
```

The above will change the background of the label to red as long as there is no `CurrentItem` in the `pumpCurvesViewSource`, but what I really want to do is change the background trigger to this:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="No pump curve selected"></Setter>
```

But this does not work (I'm guessing it is because the `Content` is already bound and my setting would override the binding).

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: A converter or a calculated property should do, if using MVVM you can go for creating a calculative property in your view model.

Comment: I want to keep my view model clean, adding properties to the viewmodel just to fix some technical issue in WPF is a last resort.

Comment: Not sure whether you still need answer. But I just came across the same problem. My fix is to set the ContentTemplate in style. That will give me new content to display.

Comment: If you write up an answer and its better than the solution I posted below I'll credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a way of accomplishing the same thing, but with a bit more code than I liked:

```
            <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource}, Path=/Label}">
                <Label.ContentStringFormat>Details for pump curve: {0}</Label.ContentStringFormat>
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource header}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource}, Path=/, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>

            <Label Content="No pump curve selected">
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource header}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource}, Path=/, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx)?

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource}, Path=/Label,  TargetNullValue='No pump curve selected'}">
```

Comment: TargetNullValue did not work, besides its not a property on the bindingsource which returns a null value, its the binding itself

Answer (score 0):

the shortest answer would be:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource pumpCurvesViewSource, FallbackValue=Your Default String}, Path=/Label}">
```